# Index error - iPhone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, vb.net, indexing, substring

I have an ASP.NET page with VB.NET code behind it. Through it, I've set up a redirecting mechanism so when it redirects there after an error has occurred, it will keep the dates selected from the user.
To do this I use the entry request, break it down and get the date. The date is in YYYYMMDD0000 format, e.g. 201708180000 so I use `.substring` to get the date.
The problem here is, on the iPhone specifically, it return a server error saying the start index of the `.substring` method is larger than the length of the string. It doesn't happen on iPad, or anywhere else, just the iPhone. Below is the line of code which causes the error:

```
Dim mobileDate1FinalOJ = mobileDate1OJ.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + mobileDate1OJ.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + mobileDate1OJ.Substring(0, 4)
Dim mobileDate2FinalOJ = mobileDate2OJ.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + mobileDate2OJ.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + mobileDate2OJ.Substring(0, 4)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the date from an iPhone? Can you suggest why an iPhone gets it wrong: what code is used to generate the date?

Comment: The indexing is correct, apparently the iPhone is returning something you do not expect.  Perhaps if you add code for a message box to display what the iPhone "sees".